# Can't access table in mysql even though it exists

Tags: mysql, select, ubuntu-server

I'm having trouble while trying to select anything on my database. If I try:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options;
```

it even autocompletes wp_options if I hit tab while writing it, but then I get the following error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'foo.wp_options' doesn't exist.

The table even shows when I do "show tables".
All other databases are working fine. This is the only one I'm having trouble with.

I'm currently running the mysql-server on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Comment: Does select * from foo.other_table work?

Comment: No.. Seems like the whole database is broken. Already tried recreating it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Perhaps drop the database and rerun your create script to see if that fixes the issue. Of course backup the existing database first. Or instead create a second database with a different name but the same table structures and experiment with that second database.

Comment: Have you checked if your syntax correctly matches the database's name? You might get this error when the case is off, e.g. foo instead of FOO.

Comment: Is your table in a database named foo?  Maybe try typing the database and table together i.e. `SELECT * FROM foo.wp_options;`

Comment: @mba12 I tried dropping the database and recreating it. The problem is I only have the .frm files as backup for the database.

Comment: @Adrian Yep... I checked a lot of times, the syntax is correct unfortunately.

Comment: @Jacob tried that too. Didn't work.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @bertZ Do you know you can use mysqldump and similar tools to create a text export of your database? You should be able to supplement your frm backup by creating exports too.

Comment: @mba12 I know... The problem is the server backup wasn't created by me. I'm just trying to restore it with the files we have from the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it.
The database was using InnoDB as the engine. Copying the old ib_logfile and ibdata files to /var/lib/mysql fixed it.